# Plot a Series or Dataframe with pandas, with a longer x-axis than actual data available

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have data until today:

```
y = pd.Series(np.random.random(23), index=pd.date_range(start='2020-03-01', end='2020-03-23'))
```

but I'd like to plot it with an x-axis that goes until April 1st (with no points on the graph for 24th to 31st):

```
x = pd.date_range(start='2020-03-01', end='2020-04-01')
```

This does not work:

```
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.show()
```

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (32,) and (23,)

**How can I make the x-axis go beyond available data?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `plt.xticks()`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = pd.date_range(start='2020-03-01', end='2020-04-01')
y = pd.Series(np.random.random(23), index=pd.date_range(start='2020-03-01',
    end='2020-03-23'))

plt.plot(y)
plt.xticks(x, rotation=35)
plt.show()
```

[image]